# android TextView setText property shows random numbers

Tags: android, textview

I am trying to use setText method for a TextView widget and fill it with a string resource as you can see in the code below:

```
TextView texthdlr = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
texthdlr.setText(R.string.someText);
```

strings.xml:

```
<string name="someText">Some Text</string>
```

but instead of showing someText value, it shows random numbers. (e,g 2131361816)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get string from resources you need to use, `getResources().getString()`

So you need to use,

```
texthdlr.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.someText));
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe `R.string.someText` is the ID of the String.

Try `getString(R.string.someText)`

Comment: but i used this R.string.someText earlier in my program in a Toast.makeText method and it worked just fine